# Matching date range in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which has start_date, end_date and corresponding bucket column. I want to map another column of dates in the corresponding date range and get its bucket.

The dataframe(df1) looks like as follows:

```
 start_date    end_date   bucket     
 2017-06-01   2017-12-31     1
 2018-06-01   2018-12-31     2
 2019-06-01   2019-12-31     3
 2020-06-01   2020-12-31     4
```

There are total 80 rows in df1.

Dataframe df2 looks like:

```
Dates
2019-08-28
2020-09-15
2017-09-13
2018-07-22
```

df2 also has 80 rows.

Basically, the Dates column in df2 has to be checked against every date range in df1 and placed against its corresponding range in a new column in df1.

Expected output :

```
start_date    end_date   bucket    Dates
 2017-06-01   2017-12-31     1     2017-09-13
 2018-06-01   2018-12-31     2     2018-07-22
 2019-06-01   2019-12-31     3     2019-08-28
 2020-06-01   2020-12-31     4     2020-09-15
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post your expected output as well? Thank you.

Comment: updated with expected output....

Comment: The dates do not overlap right?

Comment: Dates do not overlap......